What is the emunah challenge in shemitah if there is a 6th year blessing?
The Torah says that in the 6th year of the shemitah cycle there will be a special blessing, an abundance of crop that is sufficient for the 3 upcoming years, so that there will be no shortage of food during and after the shemitah year.

וְכִ֣י תֹאמְר֔וּ מַה־נֹּאכַ֤֖ל בַּשָּׁנָ֣ה הַשְּׁבִיעִ֑ת הֵ֚ן לֹ֣א
נִזְרָ֔ע וְלֹ֥א נֶאֱסֹ֖ף אֶת־תְּבוּאָתֵֽנוּ׃ וְצִוִּ֤יתִי
אֶת־בִּרְכָתִי֙ לָכֶ֔ם בַּשָּׁנָ֖ה הַשִּׁשִּׁ֑ית וְעָשָׂת֙
אֶת־הַתְּבוּאָ֔ה לִשְׁלֹ֖שׁ הַשָּׁנִֽים׃  וּזְרַעְתֶּ֗ם אֵ֚ת
הַשָּׁנָ֣ה הַשְּׁמִינִ֔ת וַאֲכַלְתֶּ֖ם מִן־הַתְּבוּאָ֣ה יָשָׁ֑ן עַ֣ד ׀
הַשָּׁנָ֣ה הַתְּשִׁיעִ֗ת עַד־בּוֹא֙ תְּב֣וּאָתָ֔הּ תֹּאכְל֖וּ יָשָֽׁן׃
And if you shall say, What shall we eat in the seventh year? behold,
we shall not sow, nor gather in our increase: then I will command my
blessing upon you in the sixth year, and it shall bring forth fruit
for three years. And you shall sow the eighth year, and eat yet of old
fruit until the ninth year; until her fruits come in, you shall eat of
the old store.

(Vayikra 25:20-22)
If so, then how is it possible ever to anybody not to observe the shemitah? Why were there punishments during the centuries (as prophets testify) for not observing it and why in modern day-Israel several "workarounds" are necessary (like Heter Mechira or Otzar Beis Din)?
If the 6th year is indeed so rich as the Torah describes, then this seems to be no challenge in the emunah. One should simply store the excess products and use it happily!

Why do people struggle to give tzedaka if we're promised עשר בשביל שתתעשר and בחנוני נא בזאת?

The question is similar to asking what nisyon do wealthy people have to steal or do any other financial wrongdoing? Or what  nisoyin do secular Jews have to work on shabbos in a country with a five day work  week?

@Shmosel Here it’s different. You already get the bounty in the sixth year before you have to leave the land alone in the seventh. In theory you don’t have to worry whether the bracha will come true - you already have what you need.

@Schmerel The question is indeed similar, but in practice, in Eretz Yisroel there are many religious people who scrupulously observes Shabbos and nevertheless feel the need to rely on heterim regarding shmita. So at least from their practice it seems that there is a distinction.

Today, when shmita is drabonon (according to most shitos) presumably the promise of the sixth year does not apply. Therefore there isn't necessarily a bumper crop

Altho God delivers a bumper crop in the sixth year and ostensibly has credit with a farmer there is still an element of faith involved as one never knows if the grain will store well nor if the eight year will produce well . .
